# Min-max AI algorithm seems to not take into account user moves when on 4x4

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, bit, minimax

My Tic-Tac-Toe minmax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning seems to work perfectly fine to play against on a 3x3 tic-tac-toe board. However, when I move onto 4x4 (desired amount of marks in a row is still 3) it does not seem to take into account potential losses, and just tries to make 3 in a row, not blocking any of my moves. For example, I will make 2 marks in a row, and instead of blocking my potential third consecutive mark the bot makes a consecutive mark for itself, thus letting me win. If anyone wonders what "Values" is, it is a list that contains all possible positions of a mark in tic-tac-toe (from 1 to 16 in this case)

```
   public static int evaluate(long desiredMarks, long undesiredMarks)
        {
            
                if (HasWon(desiredMarks))
                {
                    return +10;
                }
                else if (HasWon(undesiredMarks))
                {
                    return -10;
                }
            
            return 0;
        }
```

```
        public static int minimax(long desiredMarks,long undesiredMarks, int depth, bool isMax, int alpha, int beta)
        {
            ulong state = (ulong)((desiredMarks << Highest) | undesiredMarks);

            if (OldAnswers.ContainsKey(state))
            {
                return OldAnswers[state];
            }
            bool checkFullBoard()
            {
                foreach (int value in Values)
                {
                    if (((desiredMarks | undesiredMarks) & (1L << value)) == 0)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            
            int score = evaluate(desiredMarks, undesiredMarks);
            if (score == 10)
            {
                OldAnswers[state] = score;
                return score;
            }
            if (score == -10)
            {
                OldAnswers[state] = score;
                return score;
            }
            
            if (checkFullBoard())
            {
                OldAnswers[state] = 0;
                return 0;
            }
            if (isMax)
            {
                int best = -1000;
                foreach (int value in Values)
                {
                    if (((desiredMarks | undesiredMarks) & (1L << value)) == 0 ) {
                            desiredMarks |= (1L << value);
                            best = Math.Max(best, minimax(desiredMarks, undesiredMarks, depth + 1, !isMax,alpha,beta));
                            alpha = Math.Max(alpha, best);
                            desiredMarks ^= (1L << value);
                            if (beta <= alpha)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
                OldAnswers[state] = best;
                return best;
            }
            else
            {
                int best = 1000;
                foreach (int value in Values)
                {
                    if (((desiredMarks | undesiredMarks) & (1L << value)) == 0 )
                    {
                        undesiredMarks |= (1L << value);
                        best = Math.Min(best, minimax(desiredMarks,undesiredMarks, depth + 1, !isMax,alpha,beta));
                        beta = Math.Min(beta, best);
                        undesiredMarks ^= (1L << value);
                        if (beta <= alpha)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                OldAnswers[state] = best;
                return best;
            }

        }
```

```
        public static long findBestMove(long desiredMarks, long undesiredMarks)
        {
            int bestVal = -1000;
            long bestMove = 0;
            foreach (int value in Values)
            {
                if (((desiredMarks | undesiredMarks) & (1L << value)) == 0)
                {
                    desiredMarks |= (1L << value);
                    int moveVal = minimax(desiredMarks,undesiredMarks, 0, false,-1000,1000);
                    desiredMarks ^= (1L << value);
                    if (moveVal > bestVal)
                    {
                        bestMove = (1L << value);
                        bestVal = moveVal;
                    }
                }
            }
            return bestMove;
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using +/- 1000?  With a 3x3 Value can be 9 so (1L << 9) is 512.  Using 4x4 Value is 16 and (1L << 16) is 65536.

Comment: @jdweng But +/- 10000 is for the points, not the move value(?). I may have misinterpreted what you meant though, care to clarify?

Comment: I understand the points.  I believe your code the total point is larger than +/-1000 when you increase the grid from 3x3 to 4x4.  The best move may be 123456 but you are not getting best when you limit the range to +/-1000.

Comment: @jdweng I'm still not sure I understand. You are correct that the amount of available spots to put the mark increase when the grid is 4x4, but I don't see how the move is dependent on the value of "best". "best" is for the score, which is not the same as bestMove(?). Could you perhaps further elucidate? Thank you :)

Comment: @DisplayNamesson, I am not sure if this is the issue, but what is trying to say is that your value for win/loss is too low. Try to change +-1000 to +-inf instead and see if that solves your issue. Please also use it as a variable (winValue, loseValue e.g.) so you don't have to change onmultiple places ;)